# How to find duplicates in array without using `uniq` method

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am doing a challenge to make a method that finds duplicate values in an array, and prints out a new array without the duplicates. Ruby has a built in `uniq` method; however, I am not allowed to use it.

In my mind, this should work:

```
def uniques(array) 
  tempPos = 0
  arrayPos = 0
  duplicate = true
  result = [] # array the result will be "pushed" too
  for arrayPos in 0..array.length
    for tempPos in 0..array.length
      # If the values at the indexes are the same. But the indexes are not the same.
      # we have a duplicate
      if array[arrayPos] == array[tempPos] && arrayPos != tempPos
        duplicate = true
      else
        duplicate = false
      end
      if duplicate == false
        result[arrayPos] = array[arrayPos]
      end
    end
    puts duplicate
  end
  puts result.inspect
end
```

Output:

```
uniq *this is the short hand user input to run the method*
false
false
false
false
false
false
[1, 2, 1, 4, 5, nil]
```

I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: As an idea: `sort_by(&:object_id)` and then compare each value with the previous one to eliminate duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic works fine altough as mentioned above a `set` would work better. You could also sort the elements, and then find adjacent pairs that are the same value which wouldn't work as well as a `set`, but would have slightly better run-time than your current solution:

To polish what you currently have:

```
def uniques(array) 
  result = [] # array the result will be "pushed" too

  for arrayPos in 0...array.length
    duplicate = false
    for tempPos in 0...result.length
      # if the values at the indexes are the same... but the indexes are not the same...
      # we have a duplicate
      duplicate ||= (array[arrayPos] == result[tempPos])
    end
    if !duplicate
      result << array[arrayPos]
    end
  end

  puts result
end
```

an slightly better approach (altought still poor performance):

```
def uniques(array) 
  result = [] # array the result will be "pushed" too

  for arrayPos in 0...array.length
    duplicate = result.include?(array[arrayPos])
    if !duplicate
      result << array[arrayPos]
    end
  end

  puts result
end
```

Although this solution is OK for a learning assignment, you should note that the complexity of this is `O(n^2)` (n-squared). What that means is that for an array of size `n` (for example `n=10`), you are doing n-squared (100) iterations.

It gets exponentially worse. If you have an array of length 1,000,000, you are doing 1,000,000,000,000 iterations. This is why using a `set` is so important, it's average run-time will be much lower.

Comment: I tested your code and it doesn't work? I do see how I can make it more concise though. I also know this isn't a good way to do it for functionality - it's just practice :)

Comment: The array is not necessarily sortable.

Comment: Complete brain-fart on my part. Updated the code using your style.

Comment: Well, your new code works... My one question; why does my current code NOT work?

Comment: Your current approach doesn't remove unique elements the way you think it does. It only ensures that elements that are unique are added to the `results` array. For example, you loop over the array, and if you find a number that doesn't exist anywhere else in the array you add it. But you should also be adding numbers that do exist elsewhere, but just adding them once.

Comment: But don't I want to add numbers that don't exist anywhere else in the array; because they are unique values?

Comment: Yes you want to add both sets of numbers (unique and non-unique), but in both cases you want to add them once. Your current solution only added numbers that were unique. For example `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]`. Your solution only added numbers 2 and 3, and not 1. You also want to add 1 once.

Comment: Okay..My output though prints duplicates/non-uniq numbers:

[1, 2, 1, 4, 5, nil]

Comment: That most likely has something to do with how you were incorrectly appending to the `results` array. Try doing `result << array[arrayPos]` with your original code. Also, make sure you use 3 dots `...` in `0...array.length` and `0...result.length`

Answer (score 5):

Are you allowed to use a `Set`?

```
require 'set'
array = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]

Set.new(array).to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

An other way is to iterate over every pair in the array:

```
array.each_cons(2).with_object([array.first]) do |pair, result| 
  result << pair.last unless pair.first == pair.last 
end
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: The challenge didn't say I couldn't use 'set'... but they wanted it programmed out without the use of built in methods that would help complete the problem.

Comment: "...without the use of built in methods that would help complete the problem" seems to me an oxymoron. You're certainly going to have to use built-in methods, but if you find one that is helpful, I guess you can't use it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do that. Here's another. Suppose:

```
arr = [3,5,1,3,4,1,1]
```

Construct:

```
h = arr.group_by(&:itself)
  #=> {3=>[3, 3], 5=>[5], 1=>[1, 1, 1], 4=>[4]}
```

The duplicates are given by:

```
h.select { |_,v| v.size > 1 }.keys
  #=> [3, 1]
```

and an array without the duplicates is given by:

```
h.keys
  #=> [3, 5, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple way to so this is to leverage array.include?

```
new = []
arr.each { |x| new << x unless new.include?(x)}
puts new
```

That will give you an array (new) that only includes unique elements from the original array (arr)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate array easy way

```
arr1 = [1,3,4,5,6,6,6,1] 

arry = Array.new(arr1)

puts arry
```

Find uniq array easy way using OR operator

```
arr1 = [1,3,4,5,6,6,6,1] 

arr2 = Array.new # creating new array

arry = arr1 | arr2 # compare two array using OR operator

puts arry
```